# Why powershell becomes unresponsive

Tags: powershell

My powershell sessions become unresponsive for a while (up to 3-10 seconds), if I haven't typed a command on them in 10-15 minutes. I mean if I try to use tab completion (cmdlet execution also) after a inactivity period, it takes up to 3-10 seconds to powersehll to show the first result of the tab completion.

There is any way of avoiding this behaviour, and getting powershell more responsive all the time?

Comment: Are any of your hard drives going to sleep?

Comment: I don't think so, during the inactivity time on powershell I'm usually doing other things (text editing, coding, web browsing, configuration tasks, etc.)

Comment: Or maybe a network drive is going to sleep? When you press tab it must be searching you path. You can see what is your path is by executing this: `$env:path -replace ";","\`n"`

Comment: One thing you could try is running Process Monitor from SysInternals (it's free). Use a filter of "process name contains 'powershell'". That might give you a clue about what PowerShell is trying to do when it pauses.

Comment: No network paths in my path. Besides, as I said, cmdlet execution becomes unresponsive for a while too.

Comment: I had this happen commonly on my older machine. Windows would page it out, and I would have to wait for it to get paged in.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?

Comment: This verion:  

    $PSVersionTable.PSVersion  
    Major  Minor  Build  Revision  
    -----  -----  -----  --------  
    3      0      -1     -1

Comment: If you just press ENTER, is it slow to go back to the prompt? Try entering "NotAThing" and pressing ENTER and see how long it takes to return.  If neither of those are slow, then please provide a specific cmdlet with parameters you are using that exhibits this behavior.